# Auth.NET Akami Testing failing with new sandbox URL

Tags: testing

Language used - Salesforce APEX

We are testing Auth.NET akami integration testing using the following sandbox URL.
https://api2.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api

We are getting the following error code - E00007, it looks like the credentials we are using are not correct. Can some please contact us with a resolution.

NOTE: It is working fine with the following sandbox URL "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api" with the same login id.

regards,
Arup